# populate a dropdown from another dropdown database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am having a trouble with populate a drop-down value from another drop-down with AJAX database. So basically there are **Intake** and **Courses** in my form. So, if user choose Intake A, then courses PHP and JQuery will be in Courses option. My problem is now, after i choose Intake A, Courses option doesn't give any value. Can you please help me? Thanks

Here is the AJAX CODE

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      var list_target_id = 'Courses'; //first select list ID
      var list_select_id = 'Iname'; //second select list ID
      var initial_target_html = '<option value="">Please select intake...</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

      $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

      $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
        //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
        var selectvalue = $(this).val();
        //alert(selectvalue);
        //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
        $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

        if (selectvalue == "") {
            //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
           $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
        } else {
          //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
          $.ajax({url: 'CoursesDropdown.php?svalue='+selectvalue,
                 success: function(output) {
                    //alert(output);
                    $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
                },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
              }});
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the PHP side

```
<?php
            include "connect.php";

            $selectvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['svalue']);
            $checkuser = "Select Coursesname from courses Where CoursesIntake ='$selectvalue'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $checkuser);

            echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
            echo $result2;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                //echo '<option value=" . $row["CoursesName"] . "> . $row["CoursesName"] . "</option>"';
                //echo '<option value=' . $row['Coursesname'] . '>' . $row['Coursesname'] . '</option>';
                echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
                echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
            }

            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: i didn't see any error

Comment: what is the output> could you console.log it and tell the value

Comment: @VigneswaranS before the while happen, my option can print the value, but after the while statement, my option didn't update any value at all

Comment: @Deep I'm sorry, but where should i put the console.log()? Im newbie to AJAX.  **Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP\CoursesDropdown.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />** Is it this one?

Comment: Ah my bad.. nevermind... solved

Comment: Below this line success: function(output) {  console.log(output);

Comment: @tehkesih windy: The error you gave 3 comments above is caused by this line:  `echo $result2;` You can not echo it juste like that because it is not a string.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yeah i just realised it after i do console log. Thanks anyway